# Is there a proof for this modified Collatz-like problem?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, collatz-conjecture

The Collatz Conjecture is a famously unproven problem in mathematics, but I was thinking of a slight modification, and whether or not a proof of this different form is trivial.

Here is a statement of the original problem;

Take a starting integer n and apply the following operations; multiply by 3n + 1 if odd, divide by two if even. Take the resulting number and feed back into the algorithm. After a finite number of steps the algorithm will reach 1.

Here is a modified statement;

For any integer n you can always apply some combination of multiplying by 3n + 1 and dividing by 2 to get to 1.

The difference is that you don't explicitly define what to do in the case when a number is even or odd. Of course, you can only divide by 2 when the number you are working with is even, but in this statement, taking an even number and multiplying by 3n+1 follows the rules so, in some ways, the Collatz conjecture is a special case of this form.

Anyways, has anyone heard of a proof of something like this and if not, would a proof tell us anything interesting about the Collatz conjecture itself?

Thanks!

Comment: That modification has been discussed here (MSE) or in mathoverflow (MO) before, don't have it at the top of my mind - just search using the tag "collatz" in the two sites.

Comment: Gottfried, thanks for your suggestion. I noticed a few discussions both here and on overflow but they seemed to discuss the minimum number of steps required to reach 1, noting that it is less than the original Collatz statement, instead of proving the modified form. Here is a good review that I have been using, http://www.jstor.org/stable/2322189, by JC Lagarias. It seems to pop up on most Collatz threads. As far as I can tell from my own research, the modified form is still unproven rigorously.

Comment: Ahh, facefarm, thanks for the infos. I'm just cursory reading and won't follow your link today. I'll take it another day - thank you very much! (And good luck with further contributors here!)